# Binary operation a/b on Q+

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why isn't a/b defined on Q+? I listen to the video but did not understand the explenation.

[Definition of binary operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rpvz.png)

Using this to study on my own:
https://youtu.be/s4T9iEXErYY?list=PL91534186D7BE336B

Comment: Division in the positive rationals is a binary operation. I haven't looked at the video so can't help you figure out what it's saying.

Comment: Perhaps the video is pointing out that if $b$ is zero then $a/b$ is undefined?

Comment: That is a joke on the video.  The answer is not "no" as it seems at first, the answer is "no problem"

Comment: @GEdgar Which makes it an awfully bad joke. As demonstrated by the OP, the intended audience (people not yet knowing well what a binary operation is) may not get the joke and be confused. -- Additionally, the video continues with " the same problem for $\Bbb Z$", which might be understood as "the same problem that prevents division from being an operation on the rationals prevents it from being an operation on the integers". -- Really, learn math from a book, not from low-content-density online vids

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen... This is true.  I endorse this rule for math lecturers:  If you write something wrong, then correct it to be right, it is likely that some students' notes end up with only the wrong version.

Comment: The specific video that you linked to is 13 minutes long and is a part of a whole series of videos.  Quickly scanning through the first video I do not see a reference to the example of $a/b$ on $\Bbb Q^+$ and am not willing to sit through over an hour of video of "content" that I have already heard explained more eloquently and in more detail just to find where the videomaker possibly made a mistake or where you possibly misinterpreted what he said.  Please point to the specific timestamp in question or have your question entirely self-contained.

Comment: @GEdgar Oh, thank you so much! I did indeed heard "no". I checked with a friend who have studied abstract algebra and got it sorted out. Again, thank you for the incredibly fast response.

Comment: @JMoravitz It happens at about 2:57 IIRC